# How can I detect renaming operations on tables and columns?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, table-rename

I need to detect renaming operation on columns and tables.
I can see `alter`, `drop` and `create` operation in this query:

```
DECLARE   @filename nvarchar(1000);

SELECT   @filename = cast(value as nvarchar(1000))
FROM   ::fn_trace_getinfo(default)
WHERE   traceid = 1 and   property = 2;

SELECT   *
FROM   fn_trace_gettable(@filename, default) AS ftg 
INNER   JOIN sys.trace_events AS te ON ftg.EventClass = te.trace_event_id  
left outer join sys.all_objects o on o.name = ftg.ObjectName
order by EventSequence DESC;
```

But when someone renames a table or column on MSSQL Management Studio, I cannot detect on this query. Is there another way to do it?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a database trigger.
List of available events: `[sys].[events]` (there are `ALTER_COLUMN` event)

Example from msdn:

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety   
ON DATABASE   
FOR DROP_SYNONYM  
AS   
   RAISERROR ('You must disable Trigger "safety" to drop synonyms!',10, 1)  
   ROLLBACK  
GO  
DROP TRIGGER safety  
ON DATABASE;  
GO
```

another example: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/

Comment: On which table? on which event?